# Differentiable functions $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ satisfying the differential equation $f' = Af$, where $A\in \Bbb R^{n,n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A \in \Bbb R^{n,n}$.

I want to find all differentiable functions $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ satisfying the differential equation $f' = Af$.

Please can anyone lend a hand here?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$?

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting.  Is $A$ an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: $A$ is an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check that the family $f(t)=e^{At}y_0$, $y_0$ a constant vector, satisfies the differential equation.

Now, consider a function $g$ satisfying the differential equation, and let $h(t):=e^{-At}g$. Then 
$$h'=-Ae^{-At}g+e^{-At}g'=-Ae^{-At}g+Ae^{-At}g=0,$$
where the second to last equality follows from the fact that the exponential of $At$ commutes with $A$. Hence, $h(t)=c$ constant, and $g(t)=e^{At}c$.

Or you can use existence and uniqueness of solutions to ODE's given initial condition.